# Spring security's CSRF token - can I use pure HTML, or do I need JSP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

Could you please tell if there's any way to use spring security's CSRF tokens - inside **pure HTML** (not JSP)? 
My old applications use JSP, and easily receive spring security's CSRF token:

```
    <%-- index.jsp: --%>
    <form method="post"...>
      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
     ...
    Or:
    <head>
      <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
      <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
      ...
```

Now the company I work for wants to move to pure HTML with no templating:

```
     <!-- index.html: -->
     <html>
     ...
     Pure <form> and javascript, but how can we receive CSRF here?
```

We in the company are old timers and new to this, a consultant just told us that JSP is obsolete and modern teams should use clean ".html" pages, that the front end team can test without a running server. 
We are open to try, but the consultant lacks CSRF experience and couldn't help set this up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) is a consideration for your scenario. One of the features of it is that you can prototype using pure HTML but it still is a traditional server side rendered page, like JSP. Meaning you can open the html directly but still has dynamic content when deployed in the server.

With CSRF, Thymeleaf will automatically the hidden input to your forms. But you can continue to have CSRF tokens in the meta tags as well.

Now, if you are moving to pure HTML/JS with a SPA like React, Vue, Angular etc. you'll need to migrate your CSRF protection using Cookies via Spring Security's [CookieCsrfTokenRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-csrf-configure-custom-repository) or [have an REST endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#mvc-csrf-resolver) that allows you get the CSRF via XHR.